# Prove the $k$-th power of the logistic map with parameter $\mu = 4$ has $2^k$ fixed points

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems, fixed-points, nonlinear-dynamics, chebyshev-polynomials

I'm trying to solve an exercise in which I need to prove that the logistic map with parameter $\mu = 4$, $F_4:[0,1]\to[0,1]$, $F_4(x) = 4x(1-x)$, satisfies that for every positive integer $k$, $F_4^k$ has $2^k$ fixed points.

My approach has been to prove that $F_4$ is conjugated to the degree 2 Chebyshev polynomial $q_2(y) = 2y^2-1$, for $y \in [-1,1]$, via the diffeomorphism $h:[0,1]\to[-1,1]$, $h(x) = 1-2x$.

Given that $F_4^k = h^{-1} \circ q_{2^k} \circ h$, my final result is
\begin{equation}
    F_4^k(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos\left [2^k \arccos{(1-2x)}\right]
\end{equation}

However, I am not being able to solve the equation $ F_4^k(x) = x$ in order to find the fixed points, and I am not finding a proper method to prove that indeed $ F_4^k(x) = x$ has $2^k$ solutions for $x \in [0,1]$. Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit:
Now, I have seen that computing the fixed points of $F_4^k(x)$ is equivalent to solving the equation
\begin{equation}
    q_{2^k}(y) = y
\end{equation}
i.e., finding the fixed points of the $2^k$-th degree Chebyshev polynomials. By graphical analysis I have concluded that this equation has exactly $2^k$ solutions, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a middle approach, use the parametrization behind Chebyshev and set $x=\sin^2\theta$, $θ\in[0,\frac\pi2]$. Then
$$
F_4(\sin^2θ)=4\sin^2θ\cos^2θ=\sin^2(2θ)
$$
so that also
$$
F_4^k(\sin^2θ)=\sin^2(2^kθ)
$$
On each segment $θ\in[2^{-k-1}\pi\,m,\,2^{-k-1}\pi\,(m+1)]$, $m=0,1,...,2^k-1$, the values of $F_4^k$ span the full interval $[0,1]$, guaranteeing an intersection with the diagonal via the intermediate value theorem.